ReactJS: Echart page empty
I am trying to draw a simple line chart using echart as per this, however I see empty page.
My code looks as below.
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

export const CreateCharts = () => {

  function drawCharts(tid) {
    var chartDom = document.getElementById('chartmain');
    var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
    var option;

    option = {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
          type: 'line'
        }
      ]
    };

    myChart.setOption(option);

  }
  
  useEffect ( () => {
   drawCharts(0);
  }, []);
  
  return(
    <div id="chartmain" key="chartmain">
    </div>
  );
}

Can somebody please help me, what I am missing here.

Initially I installed only echarts. I had to install echarts-for-react. Modified code as below and it started working.
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react"; 

export const CreateCharts = () => {

    var option = {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
          type: 'line',
          smooth: true
        }
      ]
    };

    return <ReactEcharts option={option} />;
}

